# Аутентификация через VK

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, вконтакте, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Как в проекте asp.net core mvc сделать аутентификацию через вконтакте?

Для других провайдеров делал так

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(options =>
{
    options.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
    options.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
})
.AddTwitter(options =>
{
    options.ConsumerKey = Configuration["Authentication:Twitter:ConsumerKey"];
    options.ConsumerSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Twitter:ConsumerSecret"];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers):

```
.AddVkontakte(o =>
{
    o.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:VK:AppId"];
    o.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:VK:AppSecret"];
})
```

(но есть нюанс, на данный момент не рабоатет из-за изменений в API VK)

Answer (score 1):

Для авторизации существует множество готовых [библиотек](https://github.com/alekseynemiro/nemiro.oauth.dll) c подробной документацией и примерами использования.
Проблему можно и решить с помощью вот этого готового [виджета.](https://github.com/DukeNuken/Duke.Owin.VkontakteMiddleware)